# Twitter Search API multiple hash tags

Tags: python, search, twitterapi-python

I am trying to query the Twitter Search API for  several hashtags. I am struggling with the syntax.

```
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#ioc").items():
    print(tweet.created_at, tweet.text)
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('utf-8')])
```

Its works for only one hashtag. But i need to search at least two or more tags. Please help/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#hashtag1 AND #hashtag2")`
Or
`tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q="#hashtag1 OR #hashtag2")`

Comment: did you remove the '+'s from the query? I edited the answer once.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: @spatial yes, i remove "+". Work only "OR", but don work with "AND".